# how to center the div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

i want to center all the content of the div inside the container.
i tried to use  margin 0 auto and it didnt work
how can i center it?

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="text-center" style="margin:0 auto;overflow:auto;">
       <div style="float:left;width:15%;margin-right:2px;">

            <img src="PICTURES/Bruce-Crocker_311x312(2).jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            <div class="contenthover">
                <p>bla</p>
            </div>
       </div>
        <div style="float:left;width:15%;margin-right:2px;">

            <img src="PICTURES/Bruce-Crocker_311x312(2).jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            <div class="contenthover">
                <p>bla</p>
            </div>
       </div>


    </div>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Bootstrap `center-block` class on any block elements you want to center, use `text-center` for text..

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
            <img src="PICTURES/Bruce-Crocker_311x312(2).jpg" class="center-block img-responsive">
            <div class="text-center">
                <p>bla</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/65YSFBl6mF

Comment: thank you, but it's good just if you want to add one div if you add more div with float:left it will not work.